# Database sharing using SymmetricDS among different stores

Tags: database, data-synchronization, symmetricds

We are evaluating SymmetricDS for one of our applications.

We want to synchronize database among multiple stores. The data needs to flow from one store to the central database and then back to different stores.

In SymmetricDS, we are able to achieve the data flows as follows:

```
store -> central database // whenever we modify/insert/delete data in store,
```

and also from

```
central database -> store // whenever we modify/insert/delete data in central db
```

but what we require is a bit back and forth

```
store -> central database -> stores
```

i.e. store inserts a data row in its database, it should go to central db and then back to selected stores

**Edited the question as below to elaborate which table is not synced now**

We have following heirarchy

Stores
Chains of stores
There is Central DB having information of all stores and chains

Each store must have a basic information like address of all the stores within its own chain.
Store can add another store to its chain. Once that happens the added store must then get information through syncing of all the stores in this chain.

Tables are like below:

STORE_CHAINS (having mapping between STORE_ID, CHAIN_ID).

Example of STORE_CHAINS:

```
STORE_ID    CHAIN_ID
A           CHAIN1
B           CHAIN1
C           CHAIN1
Y           CHAIN2
Z           CHAIN2
```

There is a STORES table which has details about each store with STORE_ID being the primary key.

Example of STORES table:

```
STORE_ID    STORE_ADDRESS   ...
A           AddrA
B           AddrB
C           AddrC
D           AddrD
...         
X           AddrX
Y           AddrY
Z           AddrZ
```

Each store is synced a portion of the CENTRAL STORES table database with some basic information. Only those stores' details are synced which share the same chain.

For example here, if a new mapping (D, CHAIN1) is added to STORE_CHAINS table by Store C, the newly added store D should then receive through sync the mapping entry itself and details about the Stores A, B, C from the STORES table because they share the same chain CHAIN1. Also the Stores A, B will be sent STORE_CHAINS mapping entry and STORES entry for D.

Our problem is that the STORES entry for A,B,C is not getting sent to D. Only the newly created mapping (D, CHAIN1) gets synced to D.

The table STORE_CHAINS is the only one that has actually had a data changed, the STORES table has not changed. How do we ensure that the triggers of STORES table also get fired and its data is sent to all the relevant stores whenever a new (STORE_ID, CHAIN_ID) mapping is created.

We are using subselect for all cases to select which stores/store-group mapping entries should be sent. The selection logic works ok if we do an initial load for any store.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these newly added stores sync via the central db? Are then they getting registered? If yes then set the automatic initial loading to sync all data required for it

Comment: No. the stores do not sync if the mapping is directly added at central. But if any store is sent initial load, then router subselect condition works correctly to ensure it gets correct data of all stores in its chain. What do you mean by 'set automatic initial loading'

Comment: Well. How are you adding a new store? Is every store having its own symmetricds server? I'd it has to register the next thing would be there initial load when you could have ask the master data loaded

Comment: Each store has a unique id which is used as external_id for the symmetricds node. In the problem above, a new store has NOT been added to SymmetricDS. All the stores A,B.....Z were already registered. Only a new mapping between store D and store chain CHAIN1 was created. Store D already existed in SymmetricDS ecosystem as a node. All we now want is certain more rows i.e. the row for Store D in STORES database at central to now sync to STORES database at A, B and C since they now start sharing the same chain CHAIN1. Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: Please check the update on my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the value for the column sync_on_incoming_batch to 1 as explained in the documentation http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.8/html/user-guide.html#_bi_directional_synchronization

Use CUSTOM_BEFORE_UPDATE_TEXT or CUSTOM_BEFORE_INSERT_TEXT to trigger a sunny update on all dependency rows from other tables that need to get synced

Comment: Hi Boris, it seems to work. Is it also possible to get the related tables to sync. For the example above, the INVENTORY table syncs but the table which contains Products which the inventory references to using PRODUCT_ID does not sync.

Comment: Sure, you'll need to set the sync_incoming_batch to 1 for related tables' triggers as well.

Comment: Did that, still one of the table not getting synced, elaborated the question further to tell which table does not get synced.

Comment: What's the name of the table that doesn't get synced?

Comment: Got around to giving a specific example on what is not synced

Comment: Boris, just to confirm, what we would have to do is, in the CUSTOM_ON_INSERT_TEXT or CUSTOM_BEFORE_INSERT_TEXT we will have to deliberately dirty some column of the relevant row to force the firing of trigger.

Comment: yes, you can perform two updates, one to increment some timestamp value and then another to decrement it